# Create an infinitely scrolling UICollectionView without stuttering

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm trying to make an infinitely scrolling UICollectionView that scrolls automatically. When a cell is tapped in the collectionView, I need the cell to be deleted.

I have something working, but the problem is that every-time it reaches the end of the collectionView, when it's supposed to 'loop' over, it stutters and makes a jump. I know it's because I'm using `collectionView.reloadData()`. My question is, is there another way to do this without calling `reloadData` so it doesn't jump?

(Here's a [video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSfJLaUQEFk&feature=youtu.be))

Here's my code:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
var animationTimer : NSTimer!
var data = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startTimer()
}


func startTimer() {
    animationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "onFire:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func onFire(sender : AnyObject) {
    collectionView?.contentOffset = CGPointMake((collectionView?.contentOffset.x)! + 1, 0)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let xContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.width - (collectionView?.frame.width)!

    if xContentOffset >= contentHeight {
        collectionView?.reloadData()
        collectionView?.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    }
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.label.text = data[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    data.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/07/building-a-circular-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/

Comment: @Brandon How would I do that with a UICollectionView?

Comment: Check my comment again. It was edited an hour ago with the correct link.

Comment: I think the problem is when you find the xContentOffset > contentHeight , you set offest to (0,0), Which cause flicking. Try to set the offset with some uiviewanimation block, which will provide some good look too